# How to listen for multiple smart contract events?

Tags: web3js, web3.py, etherjs

Using Web3.py I understand that I can create a new smart contract event filter with:

```
Contract.events.your_event_name.createFilter(fromBlock=block, toBlock=block, argument_filters={'arg1': 'value'}, topics=[])
```

I want to listen for multiple smart contract events. My proposed solution is to use threads.

```
client = Web3Client(nodeUri=nodeUri)
event1 = client.contract.events.your_event_name()
block_filter1 = event.createFilter(fromBlock="latest")
worker1 = Thread(target=log_loop, args=(block_filter1, 5), daemon=True)
worker1.start()
event2 = client.contract.events.another_event_name()
block_filter2 = event.createFilter(fromBlock="latest")
worker2 = Thread(target=log_loop, args=(block_filter2, 5), daemon=True)
worker2.start()
```

Is it possible to filter for multiple `your_event_name(s)` in one filter? Or is the best practice to use threads?